# SmtpClient Failure Sending Message Hotmail c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email through SmtpClient. I am extracting the recipient email from a database query. However, upon trying to send I get an error with an Inner Exception of:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 65.55.176.126:578"

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
string email = query.Email;
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
message.Subject = "Your Application Status has been updated!";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test234@outlook.com");
message.Body = "Dear Applicant, we are sorry to announce to you that your application has been declined!";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 578);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test234@outlook.com", "somepassword");
try
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw new Exception( "Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Company firewall blocking access to hotmail?

Comment: How can you check if firewall is blocking access to hotmail?

Comment: Try netsh firewall show config it will show you all the ports disabled on your network

Comment: The problem is a firewall and a proxy server.  You have outlook on a company network.  All messages with port 578 are going to the proxy server which only sends port 578 to the company outlook email server.

Comment: I changed the SmtpClient to "smtp.gmail.com" and everythhing worked perfectly.